# ng-disabled on a parent variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've been looking for a similar thread but couldn't find any.
Is it possible to disable a button using angularJS `ng-disabled` directive based on a parent variable?

I have defined `vm.disableSave = true` in parent controller and I'm trying to disable save button on child controller based on `$scope.$parent.vm.disableSave`. It's not working. At the moment I'm trying

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="$scope.$parent.vm.disableSave" ng-click="vm.submit()" 
                      class="btn btn-primary submit-button top5">Save</button>
```

I am aware I can do something like `vm.disableSave = $scope.$parent.vm.disableSave` in my child controller and then do `ng-disabled = "vm.disableSave"` but is there a way to do it in one go rather than creating a new variable in child controller?

Comment: I don't think you need the `$scope` so you can just do `$parent.vm.disableSave`

Comment: @George, that didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I've edited my answer @LazioTibijczyk

Answer (score 0):

With controller as syntax we are able to use the respective controller object and retrieve any property value.

> There is no need of $parent property.No matter how deep you are in the
>   nested hierarchy. you can easily get any controller object property
>   value.

see the code below

```js
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('parentCtrl',function(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.disableSave = true
})

.controller('childCtrl',function(){
  var vm = this;
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
 <body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="parentCtrl as parent">
  <div ng-controller="childCtrl as child">
    <button type="button" ng-disabled="parent.disableSave" ng-click="vm.submit()" 
    class="btn btn-primary submit-button top5">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure ng-disabled="parent.disableSave" is correct? In vm.submit() I'm setting $scope.$parent.vm.disableSave = true; but the button isn't disabled after that.

Comment: Both my parent and child are similar ng-controller="parentCtrl as vm" and ng-controller="childCtrl as vm"

Comment: To be precise I'm using ui-routing so I define my controller within a state like controller: 'parentCtrl as vm'. I can see vm.disableSave turining true in my parent controller but that doesn't have any impact on the button disabling in child controller.